# Unable to install GWT In Eclipse Juno

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, eclipse-juno

Whenever I am trying to install GWT I am getting the following error.I tried all the solutions present on stackoverflow:1.Running eclipse as administrater 2.Updating eclipse and many others.

I am using Juno SR2, java 7

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found.   Software being installed: GWT Eclipse Plugin
>   3.0.0.201710131939 (com.gwtplugins.eclipse.suite.v3.feature.feature.group
>   3.0.0.201710131939)   Missing requirement: GWT Eclipse Plugin 3.0.0.201710131939 (com.gwtplugins.eclipse.suite.v3.feature.feature.group
>   3.0.0.201710131939) requires 'org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 4.4.0' but it could not be found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Eclipse is too old for this plugin which according to the error message requires at least Eclipse Luna (4.4). It will probably work best with the current release of Eclipse - Oxygen.2 (4.7.2)